# Agrupar lista de tuplas en diccionario de manera óptima en Python

Tags: python, optimización, group-by, itertools

Tengo una lista de tuplas con la siguiente estructura:

```
lista = [('A', 25.5), ('B', 0.14), ('C', 0.0),('A', 28), ('C', 0.3), ('B', 0.18), ('A', 23)]
```

Solo he puesto `A`, `B` y `C` pero puede contener más tipos.

A partir de esa estructura quiero llegar a agruparlas en un diccionario obteniendo la siguiente salida:

```
salida = {'A': [25.5, 28, 23], 'B': [0.14, 0.18], 'C': [0.0, 0.3]}
```

He conseguido hacerlo con la función transformar del código que pongo a continuación, pero voy a tener que hacerlo con millones de registros por lo que necesitaría optimizarlo, ya que es probable que haya formas mejores pero llevo ya bastante peleándome con esto.

Para probar, he creado una lista de 40 millones de tuplas con la función `listaPrueba` y con la función transformar que tengo ha tardado 19,63 segundos.
Si alguien encuentra una manera más eficiente, lo agradecería.

```
import itertools
import time

numero = 10000000

def listaPrueba(num):
    return [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4)] * num
lst_Pruebas = listaPrueba(numero)


def transformar(lista, diccionario={}):
    for clave, grupo in itertools.groupby(lista, lambda x: x[0]):
        for elemento in grupo:
            diccionario.setdefault(clave, []).append(elemento[1])
    return diccionario


inicio = time.perf_counter()
salida = transformar(lst_Pruebas)

print(f'Tiempo: {time.perf_counter()-inicio}')


assert sum(salida['A']) == numero * 1
assert sum(salida['B']) == numero * 2
assert sum(salida['C']) == numero * 3
assert sum(salida['D']) == numero * 4
```

He utilizado itertools porque imagino que estará optimizado para iteraciones, pero no estoy seguro, así que me da igual la manera de resolverlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiosamente un enfoque mucho más "ingenuo", sin uso de `itertools`, produce un tiempo mucho más corto:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def transformar(lista):
    diccionario = defaultdict(list)
    for letra, numero in lista:
      diccionario[letra].append(numero)
    return diccionario
```

Mientras tu implementación me reporta un tiempo de ejecución de 17.18s, la que acabo de proponer tarda tan solo 3.96s

Supongo que es redundante en tu código el llamar primero a `itertools.group()`, que tiene que iterar por toda la lista para crear los grupos, para seguidamente volver a iterar en cada grupo creado. Al final iteras dos veces por los mismos datos, mientras que mi código itera sólo una. Por otro lado, el uso de `defaultdict` hace innecesario llamar a `setdefault()`, que en tu código se estaba ejecutando `numero` veces y posiblemente era la razón principal del tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!! Te puedes creer que 10 minutos después de publicar encontré otra solución (efectivamente sin itertools), cambiando el interior de mi función por "for clave, valor in lista:" y "diccionario.setdefault(clave, []).append(valor)". Aún así esa me tarda 4,74 mientras que la tuya me ha tardado 3,86. Muchas Gracias!!